How create index patern on OpenSearch dashboard by curl
I'm running OpenSearch and OpenSearch Dashboards 2.12 using Docker.
I need to create an index pattern (Dashboards Management > Index Patterns) from the command line using curl.
I tried the following command:
curl -u admin:admin -X POST "http://localhost:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/index-pattern-id"
-H 'osd-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{  "attributes": {    "title": "logs",    "timeFieldName": "timestamp"  }}'

and recive  this response:
{"type":"index-pattern","id":"my-index-pattern-id","attributes":{"title":"logs","timeFieldName":"timestamp"},"references":[],"migrationVersion":{"index-pattern":"7.6.0"},"updated_at":"2024-12-23T05:48:31.484Z","version":"WzEsMV0=","namespaces":["default"]}

but on web interface im cant see this index patern.
Where are i`m wrong ?

did you create an index already?
